# code for .xsl bibliography style numeric in square brackets, sorted alphabetically

Tags: xslt, reference, numeric, alphabetical

I want to Create a Custom bibliography style in MSWORD 2016 for Mac, I use either the style IEEE_Reference.XSL or ISO690_numerical.XSL with square brackets (I have already modified this one for square brackets).

But 1) I need that my references are sorted in alphabetical order (not according to siting) and 2) sorted according the language of references.

What changes can be applied to the codes of one of above mentioned styles to get the references sorted in alphabetical order?

Alternatively there is also a gost-r-7-0-5-2008-numeric-alphabetical.csl style, but it is .csl file and I do not know if one can convert it to .xsl

Can anyone help with this issue?

Thank you

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you are doing/wanting. Do you mean to create a docx-file with extra styles? Show some xsl you use to make it more understandable.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.